# 'React is not defined' when installing component library that I'm trying to create using Rollup and React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, rollupjs

I'm trying to create a React component library. I'm using Rollup for bundling the files. I'm generating build folder then running `npm pack` to get a .tgz file of the library. Then I'm installing that file in another project using `file:filename.tgz` and `npm install`. But when I run the server it shows me `ReferenceError: React is not defined`. I assume this is happening because React is not included in the component library.

`rollup.config.js`

```
import { babel } from "@rollup/plugin-babel";
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";
import terser from "@rollup/plugin-terser";
import peerDepsExternal from "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external";
import sourcemaps from "rollup-plugin-sourcemaps";
const packageJson = require("./package.json");

const config = {
  input: "src/index.js",
  output: [
    {
      file: packageJson.main,
      format: "cjs",
    },
    {
      file: packageJson.module,
      format: "esm",
    },
  ],
  plugins: [
    sourcemaps(),
    babel({
      presets: [
        [
          "@babel/preset-react",
          {
            runtime: "automatic",
          },
        ],
      ],
      plugins: ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"],
      babelHelpers: "runtime",
    }),
    resolve(),
    commonjs(),
    terser(),
    peerDepsExternal(),
  ],
  globals: {
    react: "React",
  },
};

export default config;
```

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "@rahul-wos/pkg-practice",
  "version": "1.0.2",
  "description": "This is my first try at generating a component library",
  "main": "dist/cjs/index.js",
  "module": "dist/esm/index.es.js",
  "type": "module",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "rollup": "rollup --bundleConfigAsCjs -c ",
    "pack": "rollup --bundleConfigAsCjs -c"
  },
  "author": "Rahul Patil",
  "license": "ISC",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.7",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.19.6",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "@rollup/plugin-babel": "^6.0.3",
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^24.0.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^15.0.1",
    "@rollup/plugin-terser": "^0.2.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "rollup": "^3.9.0",
    "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external": "^2.2.4",
    "rollup-plugin-sourcemaps": "^0.6.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.7"
  }
}
```

This is the repo for component library: [pkg-practice - Github](https://github.com/rahul-wos/pkg-practice/tree/master)

I tried searching on stackoverflow and google. Found some results that said I should include react in the component file. I tried doing that but the error still persists.